# Hidden text field when website load and enable text field then check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript that is useful for hidden text field when website load and enable text field then check box is checked.

this is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_dropshiper" id="dropshiper_ceck">
<label><b><?php echo $text_dropship; ?></b><hr/></label>
<div class="" id="dropshiper" name="">
    <p><?php echo $text_dropship_name; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="nama_dropshiper" style="width: 97%"><br/><br/>
    <p><?php echo $text_dropship_telp; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="nomor_telp" style="width: 97%">
</div>
```

and my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // kondisi saat load pertama
    if ($("input[name='ceck_dropshiper[]']:checked").val()){
        $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
    } else {
        $('#dropshiper').attr('disable','disable');
    }
    // kondisi saat CheckNox Diklik
    $('input:checkbox[name="ceck_dropshiper\[\]"]').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#dropshiper').attr('disable'.'disable');
            $('#dropshiper').val('');
        } else {
            $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
            $('#dropshiper').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

but the code is not working

please help me to fix it.

Comment: You have typo in input name. In JS you wrote "if ($("input[name='ceck_dropshiper[]']:checked")" and I guess it should be "check_dropshiper". Line with next if have the same typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// kondisi saat load pertama
if ($("input[name='check_dropshiper']:checked").val()){
    $('#dropshiper input').removeAtr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#dropshiper input').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
// kondisi saat CheckNox Diklik
$('input:checkbox[name="check_dropshiper"]').change(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#dropshiper input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#dropshiper input').val('');
    } else {
        $('#dropshiper input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#dropshiper input:first').focus();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to incorrect `name` attribute and also try to use `change` instead of `click` for `radio` and `checkbox` elements for better accessibility.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // kondisi saat load pertama
    if ($("input[name='check_dropshiper']:checked").val()){
        $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
    } else {
        $('#dropshiper').attr('disable','disable');
    }
    // kondisi saat CheckNox Diklik
    $('input:checkbox[name="check_dropshiper"]').change(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#dropshiper').attr('disable','disable');
            $('#dropshiper').val('');
        } else {
            $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
            $('#dropshiper').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Console.log net slow buddy i already have mentioned in the edit.

Comment: @Thoh agung Narso I posted other try that and see

Comment: @ThohAgungNarso try updated one. In your code you had syntax mistake. Instead of , you have used . (dot)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_dropshiper" id="dropshiper_ceck">
<label><b><?php echo $text_dropship; ?></b><hr/></label>
<div class="" id="dropshiper" name="">
    <p><?php echo $text_dropship_name; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="nama_dropshiper" style="width: 97%"><br/><br/>
    <p><?php echo $text_dropship_telp; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="nomor_telp" style="width: 97%">
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    // kondisi saat load pertama

    if ($('#dropshiper_ceck').attr('checked')){
        $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
    } else {
        $('#dropshiper').attr('disable','disable');
    }
    // kondisi saat CheckNox Diklik
    $('#dropshiper_ceck').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#dropshiper').attr('disable'.'disable');
            $('#dropshiper').val('');
        } else {
            $('#dropshiper').removeAtr('disable');
            $('#dropshiper').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the script that is used to clear the text field when the checkbox is not checked.